# Supabase User Returning Null + Auth State Not Saved After Closing App

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-hooks, supabase

I am starting to learn React Native and using `Supabase` with React is pretty different than using it with Flutter. Right now, I have gotten email sign-in/up working and listening for auth changes to switch navigation stacks. I believe my two issues are related because the user/session might not be getting saved when updated.

The first issue is that every time the app is opened, the sign-in screen is shown, even though I signed in before closing it. I tried to set som options, including `localStorage` but that did not help. Below is my `supabaseClient.tsx` file.

```
const options = {
  auth: {
    localStorage: AsyncStorage as any,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: true,
  },
};

const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_ANON_KEY, options);

export { supabase };
```

The second issue is that I am trying something simple, just showing the `displayName` that the signed-in user has set on the `HomeScreen`, but the `getUser()` and the user from `getSession()` both return null so I cannot get the `user.id`. This causes the `displayName` to be undefined and a blank screen. Below is the code I am using to get the `displayName`.

```
export function HomeScreen() {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const user = (await supabase.auth.getSession()).data.session?.user;
      console.log("User: " + user);
      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from("profiles")
        .select()
        .eq("uid", user?.id);
      if (error === null) {
        data!.map((data) => {
          const name = data.displayName;
          console.log(name);
          setDisplayName(name);
        });
      } else {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
      console.log("Name: " + displayName);
    })();
  }, [setDisplayName]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{displayName}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: For now, my workaround is a global variable for the current session which is set in the `onAuthChanges` function. However, this does not fix my first issue of the session not being saved when the app closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had defined `localStorage` as any because of a tutorial I saw.

I needed to change this:

```
const options = {
  auth: {
    localStorage: AsyncStorage as any,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: true,
  },
};
```

to this:

```
const options = {
  auth: {
    localStorage: AsyncStorage,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: So user.id doesn't return null anymore? What about getSession().data.session.user? I still have the same issue. It's asinine.